# Resize image in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to resize an image while displaying it on form (100 * 100) in CodeIgniter, by using this function:

```
echo img('imagepath');
```

Comment: what have you tried? Adding a class to your library would be the easiest way. You would then load the library and access it with $this->library_name->img('imagepath')

Comment: CodeIgniter cannot inherently do that. You would need `gd` or `Imagick` in addition to CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it..

```
$image_properties = array(
      'src' => 'imagepath',
      'alt' => 'Me, demonstrating how to eat 4 slices of pizza at one time',
      'class' => 'post_images',
      'width' => '100',
      'height' => '100',
      'title' => 'That was quite a night'
);

echo img($image_properties);
```

**Source:** [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img)

Comment: I want to make a dynamic page where the image name will be different all the time so how i can i pass the image name to the function?

Comment: @vicky assign it to a variable and give the variable name.. `'src' => $variablename,`

Comment: @vicky how are you planning to get those image names? from database? If yes,post the code